# Parse large dataset for regression using tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am currently trying to set tensorflow up for a regression task that I am trying to solve.

I am not sure how i should feed my input data, as it stored in a certain way.

My input is a sample audio file framed for 0.5 s.  Each audio file is appended to a list, and each frame is stored as a numpy.array.

So something like this

```
#One audio set
[array([[frame],[frame],...,[frame]],dtype=float32)]
```

And the output is stored in such way

```
[array([[  4.53255900e+01,  -9.82247700e+00,  -1.22920200e+00,
         -6.81728800e+00,  -8.23808400e+00,  -1.42367900e+01,
         -4.64904100e+00,  -1.49673100e+01,  -4.75058700e+00,
         -7.54071600e+00,   5.11365500e+00,   9.80618400e+00,
         -6.03554700e-01],....,[...]])]
```

I tried to implement something which i thought would work.. but get this error message: 
Code:

```
os.chdir(dnn_train)

train_name,train_data = generate_list_of_names_data(files_train_path)
train_data, train_output_data = load_sound_files(files_train_path,train_data)


number_of_examples = len(train_data)/2
train_set_data = train_data[:number_of_examples]
train_set_output = train_output_data[:number_of_examples]

test_set_data = train_data[number_of_examples:]
test_set_output = train_output_data[number_of_examples:]
############################# Training setup ##################################
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50

# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")
n_samples = train_set_data[0].shape[0]

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")


# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)


# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y) in zip(train_set_data, train_set_output):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

        #Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_set_data, Y:train_set_output})
            print "Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
                "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b)

    print "Optimization Finished!"
    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_set_data, Y: train_set_output})
    print "Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n'

    #Graphic display
    plt.plot(train_set_data, train_set_output, 'ro', label='Original data')
    plt.plot(train_set_data, sess.run(W) * train_set_data + sess.run(b), label='Fitted line')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Error:

```
File "tensorflow_datapreprocess_mfcc_extraction_rnn.py", line 191, in <module>
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 564, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 637, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 659, in _do_call
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [2048,121] vs. [288,13]
     [[Node: gradients/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](gradients/sub_grad/Shape, gradients/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
Caused by op u'gradients/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs', defined at:
  File "tensorflow_datapreprocess_mfcc_extraction_rnn.py", line 178, in <module>
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 190, in minimize
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 241, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 481, in gradients
    in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py", line 386, in _SubGrad
    rx, ry = gen_array_ops._broadcast_gradient_args(sx, sy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 140, in _broadcast_gradient_args
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2154, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1154, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

...which was originally created as op u'sub', defined at:
  File "tensorflow_datapreprocess_mfcc_extraction_rnn.py", line 176, in <module>
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 518, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1683, in sub
    return _op_def_lib.apply_op("Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2154, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1154, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

How do I feed these into tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

tf.mul(X, W) is just scalar multiplication (and W is a scalar in your code), so the resulting shape is the same as X's shape, which looks like where the error is coming from (the only way the subtraction in the loss function could work is if X and Y had the same shape).

Do X and Y have a consistent shape across examples? If so, you may want to flatten both into row vectors with [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape)(X, [1, -1]) and tf.reshape(Y, [1, -1]). I'll call the length of these vectors X_LENGTH and Y_LENGTH. Then I would make W a matrix with tf.get_variable(name="W", shape=[X_LENGTH, Y_LENGTH]), then use tf.matmul(X, W) instead of tf.mul. The output of the matmul() will have shape [1, Y_LENGTH], which should fix the shape issues you're having in the loss function.

While you're at it you may want to make b a vector of length Y_LENGTH to get biases for each of the outputs.

Comment: X and Y don't have the same shape... X is the input in this case, and y is the output.  The shape of the input and output is as described in the above post.  Each `frame` size is the same, but do not have the same length as the nested array on the output data. 

X and Y is consistent in shape across the examples.  I tried your flatten example, but it doesn't seem to work out for me I am not sure why?

Comment: I am not quite sure why you would flatten it.. Since it is already stored in a matrix like structure? would it not be easier read in as it is stored, rather than flatten it, and create a matrix from a certain number of extracted data...

Comment: Actually each frame in each example has the same length, but the number of frames in each example may vary due to the length of the audio file.

Comment: ahh.. god dammit.. That would not matter.. each frame has the same length.